# docker build fails - "cannot allocate memory"

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My docker build fails with the following error:

```
Untar fork/exec /usr/bin/docker: cannot allocate memory
```

So I get it - no RAM :) but I can clearly see free memory as swap:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7517       7334        183          0         59        515
-/+ buffers/cache:       6759        758
Swap:         4095       2635       1460
```

Also, it seems that docker takes a huge memory chunk:

```
$ top -a
top - 03:48:07 up 18 days, 17 min,  2 users,  load average: 1.88, 0.93, 0.42
Tasks: 127 total,   2 running, 125 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 49.9%us, 14.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 13.7%id, 22.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   7697592k total,  6351288k used,  1346304k free,   138804k buffers
Swap:  4194300k total,   310324k used,  3883976k free,  1449268k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1340 root      20   0 3994m 2.1g 7548 S  6.6 28.8  64:20.43 docker
 5318 root      20   0 1499m 724m 4368 S 65.5  9.6   0:08.80 ruby
  978 root      20   0 1010m 616m   32 S  0.0  8.2   0:27.24 ruby
```

So the question is:
**why doesn't "docker build" use the swap area as extra RAM and decides to kill the build?**

Comment: what is the size of the tar file?

Comment: @user2915097 it's 200Mb. thx

Comment: can we see the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Restart the docker service. this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the error running docker on debian inside proxmox (PVE)

`Linux dockers 5.15.60-1-pve #1 SMP PVE 5.15.60-1 (Mon, 19 Sep 2022 17:53:17 +0200) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

A reboot of the whole LXC Container solved the issue for me

Answer (score -2):

**It's plain and simple. You are out of memory. You have to free memory by stopping applications.**

[Swap](https://www.linux.com/news/all-about-linux-swap-space%20What%20is%20swap) is typically one thousand times slower than real memory. There are plenty of applications that will forbid their data to be swapped, for example:

- Databases typically force some critical data to be non swappable, for performances.
- Low level system components like kernels and drivers are not swappable, for various reasons. (How to read the swap disk if the disk driver has been swapped? :D)

Docker relies on many low level primitives to run and operate containers, it's very likely that they need to have real memory available. Thus Docker cannot run when you are out of physical memory.